# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) only by webhosting

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I am trying to use the Claps feature on my website, which allows users to applaud articles, and keeps track of the applause count for each article. However, when I try to make a request to check if a user has applauded an article, I receive the following error:

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (ClapsFetch.php, line 0)

The request URL is: https://yeni.cemfirat.com/lib/Claps/ClapsFetch.php?action=check&articleFilename=information-frisst-aufmerksamkeit

Code snippet from the ClapsFetch.php

```php
// Add the input validation code here
$raw_action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
$raw_articleFilename = isset($_GET['articleFilename']) ? $_GET['articleFilename'] : '';

// 1. Check if required inputs are present
if (empty($raw_action) || empty($raw_articleFilename)) {
    exit('error: missing input');
}

// 2. Validate the inputs
$valid_actions = ['check', 'applaud'];
if (!in_array($raw_action, $valid_actions)) {
    exit('error: invalid action');
}

// Validate the article filename with a regular expression (e.g., alphanumeric characters, hyphens, and underscores)
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/', $raw_articleFilename)) {
    exit('error: invalid article filename');
}

// 3. Sanitize the inputs
$action = htmlentities($raw_action, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$articleFilename = htmlentities($raw_articleFilename, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

// Remove these lines
// $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
// $articleFilename = isset($_GET['articleFilename']) ? $_GET['articleFilename'] : '';

$origin = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/' . $articleFilename;

$file = $origin . '/_claps-ip.txt';

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

```js
async function updateClapStatus() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            `../../lib/Claps/ClapsFetch.php?action=check&articleFilename=${articleFilename}`,
            {
                credentials: 'include',
            }
        );
        const hasApplauded = await response.text();

        // If the user has already applauded, update the message to show "Thanks for your applause!"
        if (hasApplauded === 'true') {
            message.forEach(i => {
                i.innerHTML = afterClick;
            });
        } else {
            // If the user has not yet applauded, update the message to show "Applaud this article"
            message.forEach(i => (i.innerHTML = beforeClick));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to update clap status:', error);
    }
}
```

I have checked the ClapsFetch.php file, and it seems to be working correctly.

Also checked permissions.

On the localhost server virtualhost (Mamp pro) on Apple maOS I don't have the problem - only when I go online Webhosting.

Can anyone suggest why I might be receiving this error and how I can fix it? I would appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you.

I compared the Apache modules, .htaccess etc. everything is the same

Comment: Check the web server error log.

Comment: Its probably a permissions error for the lib/Claps folder. Make sure you have the proper permissions for it.

Comment: @JasonK [Thu May 04 20:27:24 2023] [core:crit] [pid 86814:tid 140500954752768] (13)Permission denied: [client xxxxxx] AH00529: /usr/www/users/yeniso/lib/Claps/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/usr/www/users/yeniso/lib/Claps/' is executable

Comment: It's a permission issue. You need to check all the directories and files. To make sure they are all readable by the web server.